# switch/mergeAll/flatten is not a function - while using http driver in cyclejs

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactivex, cyclejs

I am learning CycleJS and I see that while using Cycle's HTTP Driver, I have to merge the `response stream stream` using RxJS `switch/mergeAll` to get to the stream level. But when I try to apply those functions, I'm getting a type error: `switch is not a function` (on response stream stream).

```
  const response$$ = sources.HTTP
            .filter(response$ => response$.request.url === 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1')
  const response$ = response$$.switch()
```

Could you please let me know if I am missing something?

Answer (score 2):

[*@cycle/http*](https://github.com/cyclejs/http) `filter` returns a *metastream* so it's doesn't have the functionality of a *stream*.

To get a *stream*, after you `filter`, pull the `response$$` stream from the resulting *metastream* using `response$$`, and then `flatten` it:

```
const response$$ = sources.HTTP
  .filter(response$ => response$.request.url === 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1')
  .response$$
const response$ = response$$.flatten()
```

Now you can continue on with `map`, etc. (Available operators depend on the version of [*Cycle.js*](https://github.com/cyclejs) you're using. The latest uses [*xstream*](https://github.com/staltz/xstream) for it's *stream* engine.)

@cycle/http [`response$$`](https://github.com/cyclejs/http/blob/master/src/index.ts#L46-L48)

> With an HTTP Source, you can also use `httpSource.response$$` to get
>   the metastream. You should flatten the metastream before consuming it,
>   then the resulting response stream will emit the response object
>   received through superagent.

---

Alternatively you can simply:

```
const response$ = sources.HTTP
  .filter(response$ => response$.request.url === 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1')
  .response$$.flatten()
```

Now you have the `response$` to work with as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

`switch` is a RxJS operator, its analogue in xstream is `flatten`. The stream engine depends on which `*-run` package do you import your `run` function from. For example, if you do `import {run} from 'rx-run'`, all the source streams from drivers will come with the stable RxJS 4 interface.

All this multiple stream engine stuff is quite new, introduced with latest release. You may consider reading the [migration guide](https://github.com/cyclejs/cyclejs/releases/tag/v7.0.0)